# OAuth.io with Angular 4 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth.io

I am writing my first OAuth.io authentication-based application but am struggling to understand how to get started. I have read a lot of the [documentation on the OAuth.io site](http://docs.oauth.io/) but it is still not clear to me.

Essentially, I would like nodejs to perform the actual calls to OAuth.io and then generate a token (JWT?) to share with the Angular 4 front-end. I must say I find the language used in the documentation a little difficult to understand, and I'm not sure if this is because I'm daft or because I really ought to go and read up on OAuth in general to see how it works.

Can anyone point me to an example of how nodejs, OAuth.io and Angular JS/2/4 might work together? I have been unable to find one on the world-wide interweb. Looked on GitHub, no joy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great repo / module (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) to use for near instant Oauth (1 or 2). It is designed specifically for SPA applications, whereas Passport.js and other Oauth modules have functionality more useful for large, routing-intensive applications.

Using JSON Web Tokens is proving to be easier and more secure in 2017, which is why I recommend Satellizer for Oauth:

Full Link: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer